# Which TLogs are causing large block change in SAN snap?

Tags: sql-server, transaction-log, storage

The environment is SQL Server 2014 Enterprise Edition, NetApp storage managed by CommVault Simpana. We have 100 dbs setup on an instance, all TLogs are on the same Volume.

The SAN Admin has setup TLog backups 4 times a day with a full snap of the TLog backup volume once a night.  The retention period is 14 days so at any time the TLog backup volume has 14 snaps of the TLogs.

Recently the TLog backup volume came close to running out of space because the full snaps were increasing at a rapid pace. We attributed this to end-of-year data processing, causing a lot of block change. This up-tick wasn't expected to last and it didn't.

The SAN Admin said he has no way of knowing which TLog files were responsible for the increase in block change and in turn the larger snaps.

I know there is a disconnect between files and blocks, but I would think you could connect the dots through Simpana, NetApp or PowerShell to find out which TLogs were causing the large block change.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Good news! You don't have to query Simpana, NetApp, or PowerShell to figure out where the log file sizes have been changing.

Just query the msdb.dbo.backupset table - it tracks database name, backup date/time, and backup size. You can trend this over time. I like charting this with Excel or SSRS to show volume trends, and then I can drill down into detail to see exactly which backup is causing it.

The below query displays full backup sizes in a pivot - the 0 column is current month, -1 is last month, -2 is two months ago, etc. Note that I'm filtering for file_type = D - that's full backups. You can switch out different filters for differential or log backups if you like.

```
    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
    DECLARE @startDate DATETIME; 
    SET @startDate = GETDATE(); 
    SELECT PVT.DatabaseName ,
        PVT.[0] ,
        PVT.[-1] ,
        PVT.[-2] ,
        PVT.[-3] ,
        PVT.[-4] ,
        PVT.[-5] ,
        PVT.[-6] ,
        PVT.[-7] ,
        PVT.[-8] ,
        PVT.[-9] ,
        PVT.[-10] ,
        PVT.[-11] ,
        PVT.[-12]
    FROM ( SELECT BS.database_name AS DatabaseName ,
                DATEDIFF(mm, @startDate, BS.backup_start_date) AS MonthsAgo ,
                CONVERT(NUMERIC(10, 1), AVG(BF.file_size / 1048576.0)) AS AvgSizeMB
            FROM msdb.dbo.backupset AS BS 
                INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.backupfile AS BF
                    ON BS.backup_set_id = BF.backup_set_id
            WHERE NOT BS.database_name IN ( 'master', 'msdb', 'model', 'tempdb' )
                AND BF.[file_type] = 'D'
                AND BS.backup_start_date BETWEEN DATEADD(yy, -1, @startDate)
                                         AND     @startDate
            GROUP BY BS.database_name ,
                DATEDIFF(mm, @startDate, BS.backup_start_date)
         ) AS BCKSTAT PIVOT ( SUM(BCKSTAT.AvgSizeMB) FOR BCKSTAT.MonthsAgo IN ( [0], [-1], [-2], [-3], [-4], [-5], [-6], [-7], [-8], [-9], [-10], [-11], [-12] ) ) AS PVT
    ORDER BY PVT.DatabaseName;
GO
```

Comment: I use Idera Diagnostic Manager to track file growth.  The one thing that has me scratching my head is that no log file had any noticeable growth.

Your query shows a different story.  The database we suspected was the culprit has increased several GB over the last couple of months.

I still find it interesting that the SAN Admin apparently has no way of knowing what file growth is causing the block change.

Regardless, your Pivot table works great.

Thanks.

Comment: I ran your query which lead me down a path to find one database did have substantial increases in the log file on two separate occasions, but it didn't really answer the question why the snaps have grown exponentially.

Comment: There is a lot of block change on the full snap which can't be explained by the log file growth.  It's possible that updates on the TLog are being truncated by the TLog backups so the file isn't growing, but the blocks are being changed on the SAN. 

There doesn't seem to be a way from a SAN Admin perspective to pinpoint which file causing the block change.

Comment: Log file increases, in and of themselves, only tell a portion of the story.  The two instances where the log file increased correlate to larger snaps, but that doesn't explain the other times when the snaps were considerably larger.

Comment: If you wanted to get really ambitious and determine how many pages in the database were changing, you could either do a differential backup, or measure the number of changes in the database that WOULD be backed up if there was a differential backup now. Both of these are forward-looking though - they don't give you insight back in time.

Answer (score 0):

Given the nature of a transaction log file (TLog has circular VLF usage) you could have a big increase in the snapshots, because all the data in the TLog has been changed.

I recommend reading the following articles:

[Inside the Storage Engine: More on the circular nature of the log](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/inside-the-storage-engine-more-on-the-circular-nature-of-the-log/)

[Transaction Log VLFs - too many or too few](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/transaction-log-vlfs-too-many-or-too-few/)

[Initial VLF sequence numbers and default log file size](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/initial-vlf-sequence-numbers-and-default-log-file-size/)

and Brent's own

[Blitz Result: Multiple Log Files on the Same Drive](https://www.brentozar.com/blitz/multiple-log-files-same-drive/)

This should give you an idea how a TLog file works and why you might have a sudden increase in your TLog snapshots in Simpana.

At our shop, for example, we don't do any de-duplication on the TLog files, because of their nature. In some cases we saw an increase (yes, increase) in size after de-duplication.

Summary: If you have large changes in the data, then you would generally have large changes in the TLog files. Even more so with the four times a day backup up strategy. However, if you are just backing up TLog dumps and not actually taking a Simpana TLog backup, then your issue is equally explained with the large amount of changes in the database which result in large amount of circular changes in the TLog.

E.g. Your TLog with 4 small VLFs. 0 = no changed data ; 1 = changed data

## The last VLF has a modified page in second place

```
0000|0000|0000|0100
```

Not much happening and Simpana has created a snapshot a couple of hours ago.

## You start modifying data

```
0000|0000|0000|0111
```

Simpana stores only the last two blocks three and four, because the second block was already in the initial snapshot.

## You continue modifying data

```
1110|0000|0000|0111
```

The TLog has come around and because their is free space at the beginning there is no need to increase the TLog size

## More modifications

```
1111|1111|1000|0000
```

...and in the background because of the previous Simpana Snapshot a CHECKPOINT was set and the database engine is able to commit the data. The last VLF is freed up because of the CHECKPOINT and the database engine had some spare time to send the data to the database file(s) and no open transactions in the database.

## Even more modifications and Simpana kicks in again #

```
1111|1111|1111|1110
```

Simpana will create a large snapshot, because all the blocks have changed since the last snapshot.

Even if you had a large TLog with lots of space, you would still see a jump in the snapshot size if you have large amounts of data that are modified.